# How to get a way to distinguish the queries with union

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am creating a blog in php/mysql where the user can post text or image.

If it's a text, then it has an url like this: www.example.com/text.php?id=...

If it's a image, then it has an url like this: www.example.com/image.php?id=...

I am inserting texts and images in 2 different tables:

```
Table Image:
-id
-url
-date

Table Text:
-id
-body
-date
```

At this point, in the homepage, I need to do a query that return me latest url to text and image merged. So I need to use UNION:

```
SELECT id
FROM image
ORDER BY date DESC
UNION
SELECT id
FROM text
ORDER BY date DESC
```

But I need also a way to distinguish the type ( text or image ), so in the homepage I know if I have to use www.example.com/text.php?id= OR www.example.com/image.php?id=

For example:

```
SELECT id, TYPE_1
FROM image
ORDER BY date DESC
UNION
SELECT id, TYPE_2
FROM text
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Is there a way to do that in mysql ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT id, 'image' AS type
FROM image
ORDER BY date DESC
UNION
SELECT id, 'text' AS type
FROM text
ORDER BY date DESC
```

You'll have two columsn in your result; and you can check 'type' to see if it's image or text, to process the line appropriately.

Comment: @andrewski . . . Then the duplicates are no longer removed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - what duplicates? I'm reading the question as him having two tables, one with images, one with text, with the two being independent, in which case this solution works. It depends on what he means by 'where the user can post text or image'.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly in the `union`, because then duplicates will not be removed.  You need to do a `union all` and then remove the duplicate entries afterwards:

```
select id, type_1,
       (case when min(which) = max(which) then min(which)
            else 'BOTH'
        end) as WhereFrom
from (SELECT id, TYPE_1, date, 'image' as which
      FROM image
      UNION all
      SELECT id, TYPE_2, date, 'text' as which
      FROM text
     ) t
group by id, type_1
order by max(date) desc
```

Comment: excuse me but what duplicates are you talking about ?